# How to delete item in arraylist contains number and other elements

Tags: java

I have an arraylist It's got a bunch of elements inside.
Every element is in it it contains a set of integer numbers.
Eventually, I have a number of phone numbers.
Sometimes there's a number with a letter or code in it.
Any item with numbers with some symbols or letters I want to remove from the arraylist.

//  my code :

```
 ArrayList<String> Numsphoon = new ArrayList<>();
      
      Numsphoon.add("966556160");
      Numsphoon.add("96659336.");
      Numsphoon.add("966560809");
      Numsphoon.add("966556160");
      Numsphoon.add("966556160");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Numsphoon.removeIf(str -> !str.matches("[0-9]+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Turamarth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64558136/10819573) is spot on. The only thing for which I am writing this answer is if the first digit needs to be `1-9` and rest of the digits can be `0-9`, the regex will be `[1-9][0-9]+`

In that case, the modified solution (by Turamarth) will be

```
Numsphoon.removeIf(str -> !str.matches("[1-9][0-9]+"));
```